# How to remove text between two elements in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to remove text('/') between two elements with different class and same container in Jquery ? I need to remove slash between a.main-home and a.home. Amount of links inside .reght_pagenation is various. Is it possible ? Thank you very much.

HTML:

```
<div class="reght_pagenation">
  <a title="Úvod" href="http://www.odsavacky.cz/en">Úvod</a>
   /
  <a title="Produkty" href="http://www.odsavacky.cz/en/produkty">Produkty</a>
  <a class="main-home" href="http://www.odsavacky.cz" title="Go to Cheiron a.s..">Cheiron a.s.</a>
   /
  <a class="home" href="http://www.odsavacky.cz/en" title="Go to CHEIRÓN a.s. - English.">CHEIRÓN a.s. - English</a>
   / Suction systems
  </div>
```

Comment: whether `home` will always follow `main-home`... or whether there can be other element between them

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/85eAp/1/

Comment: yes main-home is before home always.

Comment: @ArunPJohny this is an interresting use of nextSibling

Comment: @A.Wolff something crazy :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the text node after `main-home` and remove it... the `filter()` is added just for a double check.

```
var $mh = $('.reght_pagenation .main-home');
$($mh.prop('nextSibling')).filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType == 3
}).remove()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/85eAp/)

If the structure is always assured to be same then [you can omit the filter()](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/85eAp/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much, works like a charm. Nice piece of code :)

Answer (score 1):

Use filter function like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rd6Pd/3/):

```
$(".reght_pagenation").contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType==Node.TEXT_NODE && $(this).text().trim()=="/";
}).detach();
```

Comment: They want a specific slash removed, not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filter function as follows:

```
$('.reght_pagenation')
  .contents()
  .filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
  }).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple **jQuery** markup like this:

```
<script>
  var test1 = $('.reght_pagenation .main-home');
  $(test1.prop('nextSibling')).remove()
</script>
```